# File server in C#

Tags: c#, client, server

I want to write two applications:

- Server:

  - Connect with clients
  - Send a list of files
  - Transfer a file
- Client:

  - Connect with server
  - Get a list of files
  - Download a file

I need to do it `asynchronously`. I would like to ask for an advice what to use to accomplish this task. My concern is the protocol - **how to distinguish get requests from file downloading**? These are all bytes. Can I add some flags to a `socket` I am sending bytes to?

EDIT:

It would be best to have something like this:

```
// client
var sth = server.ReceiveBytes();
if (sth.flag == 1)
   ReceivingFile(sth);
else
   ReceivingCommand(sth);
```

Comment: This sounds like something that could be pretty easily accomplished in a basic web application that scans a directory and presents a list of downloadable files to a user. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What do you need that **F**ile **T**ransfer **P**rotocol does not already provide?

Comment: I wrote two applications. These allow to connect a client to a server. The server detects that someone wants to join and it accepts it. It also sends a response. So this is just on strings. But I would like to add the functionality of sending files. My current implementation is based on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I could always try to parse first 50 bytes and try to detect commands there. So for example before sending a file I would make commandBytes append fileBytes. And the client would always read first 50 bytes of a package. But that's kind of ugly...

Comment: I suggesst you to have a look at [ASP.net Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). I'm working a lot with Web API (alos with file up- and download). If you need help with it, feel free to ask.

Comment: I would suggest having the server listen to two different ports. One for list requests and the other for download requests. Then you don't need to distinguish, if a request comes in on the first port the server sends the file list, if on the second port send the bytes of the requested file.